# Left Join - Linq está trazendo valor Duplicados

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Olá, tenho um método imprimir, que faz vários `left join`, ele está trazendo os valores que quero, porém alguns desses valores estão vindo duplicados, como mostra as imagens:

**Tabela `TabelaImposto`:**   `select TbImp_codigo, TbImp_TpMdobc from TabelaImposto`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tabela `TipoModBaseICMS`:** `select TpMdoBC_Codigo, TpMdoBC_Descricao from TipoModBaseICMS`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Resultado Obtido:** 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu método:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("imprimir2")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Imprimir2()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            var impostos = (from a in bdprincipalEntities.TabelaImposto

                            join e in bdprincipalEntities.TipoModBaseICMS on a.TbImp_TpMdobc
                            equals e.TpMdoBC_Codigo into a_e
                            from e in a_e.DefaultIfEmpty()

                            select new
                            {
                                a.TbImp_codigo,

                                e.TpMdoBC_Descricao

                            }).ToList();

            result.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(impostos));
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pelo resultado na imagem `TbImp_Codigo` é um valor diferente só a descrição que bateu, na tabela como são os resultados? porque pelo visto está certo, tipo é isso que é para trazer, tem como explica mais alguns detalhes?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta e tentar dar mais detalhe

Comment: @VirgilioNovic poderia me dizer se está mais fácil de entender ou encontrar o problema?

Comment: Só olhar na tabela que os códigos não tem identidade unica ... é por isso cara!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O campo `TpMdoBC_Codigo` da tabela `TipoModBaseICMS` não é único!

Vamos pegar por exemplo, o Imposto de código 1.
Ele tem o `TbImp_TpMdobc` de valor 3.
Ao fazer o `join` com a tabela `TipoModBaseICMS` são encontraos 2 registros:

- "Valor da Operação"
- "Lista Neutra (Valor)"

O problema não está na query, está na estrutura de dados.